# How to check SQLite database in Android Studio?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I created SQLite database in Android Studio (login form) and want to find it to check how many users I created, and for some other experiments, but I don't know where to find it. Does anyone show me right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Stetho by Facebook and it's brilliant for this. Here is the link: http://facebook.github.io/stetho/

All the documentation to set it up is there, and it's all pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the SQLite Database and every modification you did with DB Browser.

[DB Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuaQ4.png)

Here's the link to download it https://sqlitebrowser.org/

Once you install it.
go to Android Studio -> app -> assets -> and right click your database , click `Show in Explorer` then drag and drop from the folder (where databse is) to the DB Browser